# Definition of an "equivalent"

Tags: organic-chemistry

What does it mean to add "1 equivalent" of something? I looked it up on google and couldn't really find a good explanation for it.

Thanks!

Comment: An equivalent is an [equivalent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equivalent), it doesn't change its meaning in chemistry. What you are asking about is probably *molar equivalent*, but the name is also self-explanatory...

Comment: For example, read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_%28chemistry%29 and http://www.chem.ucla.edu/~harding/IGOC/O/one_equivalent.html

Comment: For detailed explanation for gen. chem, read: http://dl.clackamas.edu/ch105/lesson6acid_base_solutions.html

Answer (score 2):

An equivalent is the factor of the number of molecules you need, at minimum, to carry out a reaction. The number of equivalent depends on **your** choice of what you consider is your main reactant.

Simply put, if you take a chemical equation where A + B → C, you need 1 eq. of B compared to A, i.e. you need one molecule of B for each molecule of A.

But sometimes, you can get something like 2A + B → C, and you want to know the "number of equivalent of B you should add to A". The quantity of B is one half that of A. If you consider your main reactant to be A, then you need to add only 1/2 (aka 0.5) equivalent of B.